# AvFoundation framework, AvPlayer pause method causes a crash after app minimized

Tags: swift

I am showing mp4 video file in the background with `UIView` component and AVFoundation framework.

But it gives an error after app is minimized by app user. Because player.pause() method causes a crash as you see. Here is the error: `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

```
    import UIKit
    import AVFoundation
    import AVKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var player: AVPlayer!

    @IBOutlet weak var videoUiViewOutlet: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupView()
    }

    private func setupView()
    {
        let path  = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "clouds", ofType: "mp4")!)
        let player = AVPlayer(url: path)
        let newLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        newLayer.frame = self.videoUiViewOutlet.frame
        self.videoUiViewOutlet.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)
        newLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

        player.play()

        player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayer.ActionAtItemEnd.none

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.videoDidPlayToEnd(notification:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification"), object: player.currentItem)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(enteredBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(enteredForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func videoDidPlayToEnd(notification: Notification)
    {
        let player: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
        player.seek(to: .zero, completionHandler: nil)
    }

    @objc func enteredBackground() {
        print("scope: enteredBackground")
        player.pause()
    }

    @objc func enteredForeground() {
        print("scope: enteredForeground")
        player.play()
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Video should pause after app is minimized. And video should continue after app is maximized.

Comment: You should be using the `applicationDidEnterBackground` and  `applicationWillEnterForeground` function in appDelegate file.

Comment: Can you write the exact code as an answer please? @chirag90

Comment: In which line are you getting the exception?

Comment: enteredBackground() function, player.pause() @PGDev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you haven't assigned the value to `player` property of the class `ViewController`, i.e.

```
private var player: AVPlayer!
```

And since it is a *forced unwrap optional*, it'll have `nil` as its default value. And using it in `enteredBackground()` method will result in *runtime exception*.

**Solution:**

In `setupView()` method, replace

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: path)
```

with

```
self.player = AVPlayer(url: path)
```